# AWS device farm cannot find .xctest in ipa

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, device

I am using aws device farm to test my iOS and android application.

It asks for the .ipa for xctest and xctestUI test cases which I provide by compiling them in xcode and exporting them under adhoc distribution.

Every time I drag and drop it I get that either the plugin folder is missing (fo UI testing) or that the .xctest directory is missing.

Is there a way to have everything included when using xcode to export?

Comment: Why is this question under `android` tag?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the error? Also are we using xcui or xc tests? The test package should be different depending on which one is selected.

Comment: Any update here?